# Why is my program compiling but not doing anything?

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array

So I'm working on a program and I'm initializing a 2D array with zeroes like so:

```
  int studentGrades[3][2];

   for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
    for(j = 0; j <= 2; j++){
        studentGrades[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

printf(" %d", studentGrades[1][2]);
```

This compiles but does not do anything in the console, and will not advance past this point.

I've looked over it for a long time and I just can't crack it. 
Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to include a line below the code to print out a position in the array, but the program doesn't get past the loop.

Comment: Read [ask], especially the bit about including only a [mcve] -- not a snippet, and not all of your code.

Answer (score 2):

A problem in what you're showing is the `<=` in the loops. Since arrays are 0-based the last addressable location is `n-1` where `n` is the size of your loops. So you are definitely going over the bounds of your array. That will cause a problem at some point. Also you aren't declaring `i` or `j` but that would have been caught by a compiler so you must be somewhere.

As for why you don't see any output nothing in your code above prints anything.

you need a loop to print the results. Something like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        print("Grade[%d][%d]: %d\n", i, j, studentGrades[i][j]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Something that, sadly, would have been plainly obvious after the most trivial attempt at debugging, like putting a printf inside the loop as you have done.

Answer (score 1):

> ... but does not do anything in the console...

What do you expect it to do in the console? You are never calling print statements or reading from stdin in the code snippet you have provided.

As a heads up, this is incorrect looping:

```
int studentGrades[3][2];

for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
   for(j = 0; j <= 2; j++){
      studentGrades[i][j] = 0;
   }
}
```

Your array is 3x2, so you cannot access indices `studentGrades[3]` or `studentGrade[AnyNumber][2]`. Your accessible index ranges are 0-2 for rows and 0-1 for columns. As such, your loop should be:

```
int studentGrades[3][2];

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      studentGrades[i][j] = 0;
   }
}
```

As for why you are not getting console I/O, I have no clue because the code snippet provided does not ever attempt to interface with the console.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you mean that you expect some kind of output from the code that you posted above. You don't have anything in your code such as a printf that writes output to the console. To do this you would have to include the preprocessor directive by doing `#include <stdio.h>` then using printf to print the contents of the array to the console.